# controlling MultiThreads

Tags: java

I have array with 24 element
and I need to create 10 thread and one controller thread
the task of controller thread is to allow some threads to access the array and prevent some of them according to  a specific criteria.
the main question Can we control all the threads with one controller thread
and can we make sure that the threads that can access array finished accessing the first element in array before they access the second element.
thanks

Comment: I'd suggest reading Java's concurrency tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are looking for [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)s.

I would suggest you create a lock for each group of elements you wish to control independently and hold them in the controller. All non-controller threads can take a read lock while the controller controls access through write locks.

The main feature of `ReadWriteLocks` I am suggesting you use is the ability to grab and release read locks from multiple threads very quickly but attempting a write lock will wait for all read locks to be released and then block all new read locks until the write lock is released.